# Resources for learning ARC in iOS 6

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I learnt the basic concepts of memory management with earlier versions of iOS but am now looking at using iOS 6 and am struggling to find up-to-date documentation.

If you could direct me to any iOS 6 documentation relating to memory management (aimed more at the less experienced, I have a Java background) it would be very helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're a registered iOS developer, watch the WWDC 2011 video [Introducing Automatic Reference Counting](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=323) and [Adopting Automatic Reference Counting](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=406) from 2012.

And of course there is the official [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html).